# Download blob PDF file in Cypress JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to download pdf file from a web site in to my cypress automation project structure. I've tried to use [cypress-downloadfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-downloadfile). This module worked fine for the following basic example as explained in its documentation.

```
cy.downloadFile('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg','mydownloads','example.jpg')
```

But this module thrown an error for the blob URL in download.

Application:

[image]

DOM:

```
<a download="mited Order Confirmation-zM9wwMcv3zff.pdf" class="btn btn-block btn-white-animated" href="blob:https://test01.mited.com/ff9eeaa0-c185-4e16-b7f8-d82e035d8645"><span>DOWNLOAD DETAILS</span></a>
```

Following is the download file Code:

```
orderConfirmation.buttons('downloadpdf').should('have.attr', 'href').then((href) => {
  cy.log('href: ' + href);
  cy.downloadFile(href,'mydownloads','example.pdf')
  cy.log('Payment Complete')
})
```

Following is the error given by cypress-downloadfile module:

[image]

How to download this kind of blob file from JavaScript project.